# git change the parent branch

Tags: git

The short story is :
I have created Branch **A** out from the **Develop** Branch 
then I created Branch **B** From Branch **A**

We decided later that we need to include the branch B in the next release and A will not be included

what I am planning to do is :

1. delete my First pull request for B
2. create a new branch B1 from Develop branch
3. cherry-pick the commits I need
4. then delete the old B branch
5. rename B1 to be B
6. create a Pull Request for the new Branch B

so I was thinking if there is a way to change the parent of B branch to be **Develop** instead of **A** to avoid this mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that your current branch diagram looks something like this:

```
develop: A -- B
               \
branchA:        C -- D -- E
                           \
branchB:                    F -- G
```

You want the B branch to look like this:

```
develop: A -- B
               \
branchB:        F -- G
```

Rebase onto can be used here:

```
git rebase --onto B E
```

In plain English terms, the above command says to place the commit whose parent is `E`, which is the `F` commit (and the start of the B branch) onto a new base which is commit `B` in the `develop` branch.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `git rebase --onto`, since what you want to do is basically rebase *only* the commits from `branch B` onto `develop`.

There is a very good description of rebasing in [the official git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing). See section *More Interesting Rebases* for an example like yours.

Your example would be solved by
`git rebase --onto develop branchA branchB`.

Also see the [git rebase documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).